What are these soldering materials?
I'm seeing many videos like this:
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/ZhSoJAQTEuY?feature=share
Guy applies something (what is this? Solder paste?) onto the PCB:

Then he applies hotair:

After soldering it looks like this:

Then he applies something else (what is this?):


Yes, solder paste. Rather too much of it, you can see a ball on the LH side that mysteriously disappears in the jump cut. Another ball near the leads gets melted in, apparently.

For production the solder paste would be applied by a stencil so it would be a uniform thickness and largely confined to the pads.
The second is solvent, such as isopropanol and a brush to clean off the residual flux.

isopropanol: is it "Isopropyl Alcohol" with other words?

There are paste dispenser robots also. Removes the need of stencils but it's slower to apply.

@Daniel Yes, exactly.

"Yes, solder paste. Rather too much of it, you can see a ball on the LH side that mysteriously disappears in the jump cut" really great! +1

Yes, ‘isopropanol’ is a more systematic (and shorter) name for ‘isopropyl alcohol’.  (The preferred IUPAC name is ‘propan-2-ol’, which is even more explicit.)

The first material is solder paste, which is essentially finely ground-up solder mixed with flux. They then heat it to its melting point, which makes the solder wick up at the pins and pads.
Notice also how the part 'centers' itself when they heat it: that's the melted solder's surface tension doing its magic.
The second material is isopropyl alcohol to clean off the flux. This is typical for a rework like this, as flux residue can affect circuit performance over time, and it just looks bad.
In production soldering they will often use a water soluble flux and clean with deionized water, or sometimes they'll use a 'no clean' flux.

What's surface tension depending on? I.e.: if I wish to have better tension, shall I use solderpaste with higher/lower/different flux concentrate?

@Daniel By the time the surface tension of the molten solder comes into play, the surface tension of any remaining flux is not a factor. Note that the video shows someone using a practice board - that's a Good Idea before soldering a real circuit and they are available for not much money.

The trick goes this way - any interface has some surface tension and it depends on both materials "touching". The "magic" happens when there are three (and more) in contact - then the geometry of the tripple- (or more-) point depends on all pairs possible. In the most common case it is called wettability or water droplet contact angle - [W]DCA. Here you have four materials - copper, PCB, solder and flux. Those are designed that solder has much lower DCA with copper than with PCB (surrounded by the flux). It's easy to see the solder "prefers" contact with the pins and pads over the PCB.

@Crowley: thx! so in case solder has much lower DCA with copper than with PCB: can I select better solder? I.e. is there any solderA, which has lower DCA with copper than solderB?

@Daniel The difference between DCA for copper-solder-flux and PCB-solder-flux contact is different enough to work - You don't need to find improvement here. Also note how smooth the PCB needs to be.

The first material is solder paste, which are small balls of solid solder. They tend to wick to exposed metal when heated beyond melting point.
The second material i am unsure of.  It could be flux, though it seems too late for flux at that point in the soldering process.
It could also be a conformal coat, though one would assume they would focus on the pins and not the package (as your photo suggests).
Or they're just cleaning it, with alcohol or a flux remover.  What did they do after applying the second material?

"What did they do after applying the second material?": after applying the second material it kindof cleans the surface of the PCB. You can see the YouTube short at the beginning of my question to see :)
